# get dropbox status via commandline

Tags: dropbox

I want to check the dropbox status via CLI so I login and enter. (this happens locally and on remote host)

```
 $ dropbox status
```

Dropbox responds with this :

```
 :> dropbox status
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/apex._apex.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/tornado.speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/wrapt._wrappers.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
 Another instance of Dropbox (680) is running!
```

However :

```
 :> which dropbox
 /usr/bin/dropbox


 :> pgrep -fa dropbox
   680 /usr/bin/dropbox
```

How can I get the status of dropbox without dropbox thinking I'm starting it. Even

```
 :> dropbox help
```

responds with the same output as above.

Comment: Have you tried stopping that dropbox instance (in your case 680) and then restarting the dropbox service?

Comment: Good suggestion but not what I'm looking for. Dropbox is running on the machine and my experience with Dropbox on Linux leads me to caution. We're not looking at an error -- I don't think -- we're looking at a missing feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix :

```
 wget https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/dropbox.py
```

put `dropbox.py` somewhere along your PATH and make it executable.

To avoid a deprecation warning the current version needs an edit at line 612.

Change

```
           if self.stop_event.isSet(): break
```

to

```
            if self.stop_event.is_set(): break
```